# Ubuntu Mate 18.04 32bit on MD E1210: Power management shall not invoce sleep mode when tasks are running

Tags: power-management, mate

I have Ubuntu Mate 18.04 32-bit running on an old Medion E1210 netbook. I set the power management to go to sleep mode after 1 hour of idle time when connectet to the power grid.
But what I get: when the computer is idle, it will take much longer than 1 hour until it goes to sleep mode - on the other hand, when it's executing some heavyload tasks it will go to sleep mode after some time even when those task are still running.
I thought there must be something wrong with idleness detection, I didn't know that it only refers to user interaction. Now is there a way to bypass sleep mode automatically while the system is idle but heavy tasks are running? Of course I could change the settings to never sleep and invoke it manually, but those tasks are running during the night so I won't be there when things are finished.

Comment: System being idle does **not** relate to tasks running/executing; but whether or not it's being actively used by a user (ie. no mouse/keyboard etc activity).

Comment: OK this explains the behaviour. I will alter the question.